# tomcat installation exception

Tags: tomcat, windows-7, installation

I'm trying to install tomcat-7.0.27 on windows 7.
I then clicked bin/startup.bat, a window shows up and I see "INFO: Server startup in 761 ms" at the last line.
I then try to check "http"//localhost:8080" but the infomation belowe shows:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No output folder
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No output folder
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createOutputDir(JspCompilationContext.java:738)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getOutputDir(JspCompilationContext.java:196)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getClassFileName(JspCompilationContext.java:581)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.isOutDated(Compiler.java:461)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.isOutDated(Compiler.java:425)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:639)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
```

I then found this information at the every beginning of the window:

```
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\logs\catalina.2012-05-14.log (Access is denied)
```

Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: you don't have to install it, just unzip and then run catalina.bat start to actual start the server.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Windows 7 makes it easy to run into such trouble when you are not careful enough installing things. You will have to make sure that the SYSTEM user has full access to the Tomcat folder, so that when Tomcat runs, it can freely create folders and files within its own directory.

Comment: I tried unset Read-only, but the attributes is always selected. How can I give it the right permission?

Comment: Right-click on the Tomcat folder, select "Properties", go to the "Security tab", select the User "SYSTEM", try to give it full control.

Comment: I checked the Security tag and I see SYSTEM has "Full control".

Comment: Maybe you are not running Tomcat as a Windows service? How do you start Tomcat?

Comment: by double click on startup.bat

Comment: I am not sure who the user would be in this case, maybe yourself... You can check which user is used to run Tomcat by going to the Windows "services" utility (you can open it by clicking on the Start button and typing services, then clicking on the gears icon). This will show all the services running, including Tomcat, and the user each service is logged on as.... alternatively, you can right-click on the startup.bat file and choose "Run as Administrator"... this might solve your problem as well.

Comment: It works now, both double click and "Run as Administrator", not sure why. But previously I cannot run it as administrator.

Comment: I gave full control to the USER in security tab and it worked

Answer (score 18):

The problem is that the user that is running Tomcat lacks file permissions (read/write) in the install folder.

Solution

Right-click on the Tomcat folder (apache-tomcat-7.0.29), select "Properties", go to the "Security tab", try to give it full control to any users profile in you pc, just for be sure.

Then, click again to C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\bin\startup.bat and wait for self creation of the folders by the application "startup.bat".

---

Other option is manually (I created the following directories by hand):

- apache-tomcat-7.0.14/work/Catalina/localhost:
- apache-tomcat-7.0.14/work/Catalina/localhost/_
- apache-tomcat-7.0.14/work/Catalina/localhost/docs
- apache-tomcat-7.0.14/work/Catalina/localhost/examples
- apache-tomcat-7.0.14/work/Catalina/localhost/host-manager
- apache-tomcat-7.0.14/work/Catalina/localhost/manager
- apache-tomcat-7.0.14/config/Catalina/localhost/
- apache-tomcat-7.0.14/logs

Comment: Thanks, this was a big help for me after I installed a new version of Netbeans. But then when I tried starting Tomcat within Netbeans and running an app I would get all sorts of access denied messages for log files and warnings about work directories.

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me:
Go to your tomcat installation bin directory, for me:
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\bin.
Right-click "startup.bat" and select "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 4):

google directed me here when searching for:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: No output folder
```

I am a Mac OS X 10.8.2 Mountain Lion user. What I needed to do was, after going to usr/local

```
sudo chown -R <YOUR_USERNAME> apache-tomcat-7.0.34
```

Of course everything happens in Terminal. You should also **pay attention to change numbers in folder name appropriate to your apache tomcat version.**

Comment: Worked for me on ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have required access rights for creating folders inside your system drive.

You can solve this by

1. right click "startup.bat" located in the "bin" folder of your apache installation.
2. Click "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 2):

Check whether CATALINA_HOME environment variable is set to correct tomcat path

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the solution.

this problem is solved in my computer with below step.

1. right click "startup.bat" located in the "bin" folder of your apache installation.
2. Click "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem but it can easy be solved with administrative rights,just opened command prompt with administrative rights and it worked!!! 
Hope will help others..

Answer (score 0):

if this was working for you previously, sometimes the work directory is simply in a bad state and you can fix it by deleting it and allowing tomcat to create a new one from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem with windows 8 and running the "startup.bat" was not working.

I fixed it by going to my JazzTeamServer Folder  (i was installing Jazz CLM), right click in the folder, properties, security, edit, and mark as full control for the Group that you are using.

After that, the Tomcat server is able to create all the folders that it requires.

Hope this helps, this is my first answer in SO.  ;)