# HTTP 404 when trying to run a jsp file in eclipse

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I get 404 error when trying to run a jsp file eclipse. The confusing thing is the server is running and I can go to `localhost:8080` without any problems. I have attached an image of my configuration of server, the jsp file and also the location of the file and the error.

[image]

I embed the image cause of the reputation thing so I have linked it

More information:

I am using TOMCAT 7, ECLIPSE KEPLER I have checked the location of `helloworld.jsp` its in WebContent. I have restarted the server.  I have created another dynamic web project nothing works. I get the same problem I can go to `localhost:8080` but I cant run an JSP file

**SOLVED:**

Okay guys its pretty simple to solve this problem. There are two things you need to try.

1)Right click your project and export the war file into `C:\ProgramFiles\Tomcat7` folder 
If this does not work then.

2) Right click your project and export the war file into some directory and copy the war file into `C:\ProgramFiles\Tomcat7` then start the Tomcat server and there you go your JSP file work.

You will probably end up doing step 2 because of stupid windows file permissions

Also thanks for all the help guys really appreciate it.

Comment: If you go to the `Servers` tab and expand the Tomcat server, do you see your application?

Comment: post you pom.xml and web.xml file

Comment: Check the path of your jsp is correct in web.xml.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Rp8Bw7Mi this is the web.xml not sure what is pom.xml.

Comment: Restart you tomcat server

Comment: I did restart my server it does not help. I can go to localhost:8080 no problem but when I try to run helloworld.jsp I get HTTP 404 error. I have configured everything I have tried everything but I still get the error when trying to run helloworld.jsp

Comment: Right-click your project, select Properties and `Web Project Settings`. What is the value?

Comment: @user3135774 go to your worksspace and check whther helloworld.jsp is present in webcontent folder or not?

Comment: sotirios the value is HelloWorldJSP

Comment: @JquerLearner  if you look at the image I posted the helloworld.jsp is in the webcontent folder.

Comment: Right click your project, go to properties, go to `Deployment Assembly`. What do you see?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis http://imgur.com/eBrUVH7 this is what I see

Comment: First of all create a simple web-application directory and keep minimum required files in it, like web.xml and your jsp accordingly. Paste this in webapps folder of tomcat and try by starting server to access your jsp.

Comment: What's shown in the Console view when the server is starting?  Anything that might indicate a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that u have put your Jsp files into the WebRoot and check the location and even check your Web.xml and after that run and still if its not working then post your Web.xml here.

Comment: what do you mean webroot you mean webcontent

Comment: Try it and m sure that is only the reason why u getting that error.

Comment: I have already tried that you need to check my orginal image its got nothing to do with that

Comment: i checked that then do one thing paste your web.xml file here.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, user3135774's solution does not work for me, as am using an Apple computer.

I have read and researched another [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348741/message-java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-output-folder) (Error 500: No Output Folder), which I have along with Error 404, carefully, and I think this is related to permission issues.

The JSP file is supposed to be compiled and then deployed under `Tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/YourProjectName`. The 404 error message means that there is no files in that directory. Since Eclipse has no write permission to this directory, you have to change the access permissions. After changing the permission to `777`, there we have the compiled .java and .class files.

Comment: @tac as user3135774's  solution does not work for me, do you have any idea how would I solve it?

Comment: If 777 is not a good idea, other numbers may be set for proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have any of them

```
index.html/index.htm/index.jsp/default.html/default.htm/default.jsp page
```

To run your `jsp` page :

In Eclipse:

=>goto Java Resource

=>right click on your jsp page

=>in that select Run as Server.

Comment: Did you put war file in your server

Comment: what do you mean war file

Comment: @user3135774 Can you check A folder "HelloWorldJSP" is inside your tomcat folder( `C:\ProgramFiles\tomcat7\webapps` )? If so Can u check whether the JSP file is there?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So what? If its embedded also the project should b copied to tomcat webapps folder

Comment: @ShijuKBabu hey yeah HelloWorldJSP is not in C:\ProgramFiles\Tomcat7\webapps

Comment: @ShijuKBabu  I am confused why should HelloWorldJSP be in that directory because I have created the folder in eclipse shouldnt it be in the eclipse workspace directory

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in that image the tomcat directory is mentioned.

Comment: @user3135774 Tomcat server is embedded with eclipse. So it copies your project into tomcat webapps folder

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `http://i.imgur.com/xYpdz3R.jpg` in this link, left bottom image, its tomcat config

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis see the bottom. The server path is mentioned.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis then why should that location is mentioned in eclipse?

Comment: @ShijuKBabu  do you guys think I should copy the HelloWorldJSP folder to C:\ProgramFiles\Tomcat7\ webapps folder would that work?

Comment: @user3135774 No, there is a specific format it needs to be deployed in. Eclipse should take care of doing that.

Comment: @ShijuKBabu I guess you can specify the actual Tomcat installation dir.

Comment: Well thats what its mentioned I guess

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis cool, so any recommendations what do you think I should do. I can reinstall eclipse and tomcat but I want that to my last resort

Comment: @PankajJawale I will have a look at that but I think I followed a similar tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

After applying everythings, it did not work for me to read image file in eclips.

**Finally, It works! after that I change deploy path.**

Server Locations>Deploy path(Set with "Workspace" of Eclipse)

[image]