# Why can not pass Gui User in jUDDI

Tags: apache, web-services, tomcat, uddi, juddi

After Configuration server Juddi in Eclipse and create environment variable
we get Problem to access to page Gui user and admin and tomcat interface :

[image: Can't passing to Gui user]

[image: Can't passing to Tomcat]

[image: Can't passing to jUDDI]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at something like :

[message java.lang.IllegalStateException: No output folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348741/message-java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-output-folder)

I would check the Tomcat logs, the permissions of the user you are running tomcat under, and check the directory that you have installed your tomcat into.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not even try to use UDDI**

these days. People are moving towards semantic web services ,UDDI is out of the scene. 
WSMO and OWL-s are major initiatives for semantic web services. These solutions can provide more precise results.

**Here's a few**

- mDNS/Bonjour/Avahi - can be used to share endpoint information for a web service, or anything else using a TXT record
- WS-Discovery - supported by CXF and WCF, shares implementation of a specific interface
- ebXML - had a component similar to UDDI

[visite this  link](http://cxf.apache.org/)