# how to deploy java tomcat project made in RHEL 5 in Windows tomcat?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6, web.xml

I am new to tomcat . 
I have made jsp servlet java project on linux RHEL 5 using mysql 5 database.
Now i want to deploy that java project on my windows tomcat server.
I tried to deploy it, however i am getting HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: No output folder error.

My Questions are:
1.Do i need to make any code changes as i am deploying linux project into windows.
2.Do i need to make changes in WEB.XML or i have to create any other config file.
3.How the NO OUTPUT FOLDER error will be resolved.

Please help.

Comment: That is very minimal information impossible to debug. Java is a platform agnostic language, your code will run anywhere JVM runs (including Tomcat), however it's very easy for unaware programmer to introduce OS specific code. The answer to this question might lie within your code itself, it's impossible to create generalized answer for a question like this

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577494/tomcat-installation-exception SYSTEM user needs full access to the Tomcat folder

Comment: @developerwjk Oh great ...!! it worked it was access issue.
Now i  am not getting Status 500 error.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an access issue.
Provide Read+Write access to tomcat folder.